# Acquire/Release Memory Ordering

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

In the example:

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> data;
std::atomic<int> flag = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(0);

void thread_1()
{
    data.push_back(42);
    flag.store(1, std::memory_order_release);
}

void thread_2()
{
    int expected=1;
    while (!flag.compare_exchange_strong(expected, 2, std::memory_order_acq_rel)) {
        expected = 1;
    }
}

void thread_3()
{
    while (flag.load(std::memory_order_acquire) < 2)
        ;
    assert(data.at(0) == 42); // will never fire
}

int main()
{
    std::thread a(thread_1);
    std::thread b(thread_2);
    std::thread c(thread_3);
    a.join(); b.join(); c.join();
}
```

1- If I replace std::memory_order_acq_rel in thread_2 by std::memory_order_acquire, can I still guarantee that the assertion in thread_3 will never fire?

2 - Can std::memory_order_release synchronize with 2 threads using std::memory_order_acquire (if 2 threads are watching over the same flag with acquire semantics)?

Comment: FYI, `ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(foo)` is provided for C compatibility, `std::atomic<T> flag{foo};` has exactly the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have nothing to synchonize-with in thread 2, so std::memory_order_relaxed memory ordering is more rational here.
2. The std::memory_order_release tagged store of variable `x` synchronizes-with std::memory_order_acquire tagged load of variable `x` even initial store is followed by sequence of atomic read-modify-write operations on `x`